# In Scala, how to stop reading lines from a file as soon as a criterion is accomplished?

Tags: scala, file-io, loops, csv, break

Reading lines in a foreach loop, a function looks for a value by a key in a CSV-like structured text file. After a specific line is found, it is senseless to continue reading lines looking for something there. How to stop as there is no break statement in Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previous answers assumed that you want to read lines from a file, I assume that you want a way to break for-loop by demand.
Here is [solution](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/control/Breaks.html)
You can do like this:

```
breakable {
   for (...) {
     if (...) break
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 9):

Scala's `Source` class is lazy. You can read chars or lines using `takeWhile` or `dropWhile` and the iteration over the input need not proceed farther than required.

Answer (score 6):

To expand on Randall's answer. For instance if the key is in the first column:

```
val src = Source.fromFile("/etc/passwd")
val iter = src.getLines().map(_.split(":"))
// print the uid for Guest
iter.find(_(0) == "Guest") foreach (a => println(a(2)))
// the rest of iter is not processed
src.close()
```

Comment: Watch for exceptions on empty lines!

Comment: Good example for me, but it raises one more question: how do I skip first line, which is a table header?

Comment: `val iter = src.getLines().drop(1).map(_.split(":"))`